# How to hide a tab in Android tab layout?

Tags: android

I have a tab layout containing 3 tabs. I want to add 4th tab at run time and hide this tab after some time. Please let me know how to hide a tab in Android.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Get  `TabHost` from resource as

```
TabHost  tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

Then runtime use this

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Supposing that you are trying to hide 4th Tab.(`So 3 is used`)

Comment: Thanks worked for me, my initial approach used `removeViewAt(...)` which works 2.2+ but crashed with 2.1.

Comment: Note that you should probably use getChildTabViewAt, not getChildAt

Comment: Both seem to behave the same; is there a difference?

Comment: TabLayout and Tab host are two different things

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm building an app that use a **FragmentPagerAdapter** as SectionsPagerAdapter in an activity. This activity was generated by AS and its layout has a **TabLayout** with some **TabItem**s.

I wanted to hide one of them if var **hide** is **false**. Then I used:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.sectionBar);
if(!hide) {
    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(2);
    if(tab!=null) {
        tabLayout.removeTab(tab);
    }
}
```

I know that remove is not hide but it was my solution.