# Display multiple sayings as separate Activity in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am very new to Android development and so I am seeking advice for the best means to implement the following...

I would like to display a few famous sayings in an app - one page at a time, with back and next button navigating to the previous and next sayings. Just like below...

[image]

For this...

1. Do I have to create a separate `Activity` with its `Layout` for each page (famous quote screen)? (If there are 20 quotes then do I have to create 20 Activities?)
2. If yes to question 1, then do I need dedicated "Back" and "Next" buttons for each page? (Is there any way of using the same back & next buttons globally)?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ViewPager` and `Fragment`s. This way you don't have to create separate `Activity`s and `Layout`s. You just had separate pages for each new screen. You also won't have to create new buttons for each page.

Check out the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) about getting started with it

[This tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-horizontal-view-swiping-using-viewpager-and-fragmentpageradapter-in-android/) is a good one to see how to use `ViewPager`. It steps you through using it and has source code that you can download and tailor to what you need it for. This is a good way to keep the `Layout`s consistent with less code which is probably what you would want for something like this

Comment: Thanks @codeMagic. I am leaning towards using `Fragment's`. Thank you for the tutorial link as well.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need separate activities.  Just one will do it.  Make your activity have a pageNumber variable, default it to 0 on creation.  When they hit back or next, increment it.  Then call setText on the TextView holding the quote and change it to the new quote's string.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a tabbed layout and hide the tabs.  This should help with how to hide the tabs.
[How to hide a tab in Android tab layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026653/how-to-hide-a-tab-in-android-tab-layout)