# Android how to hide tab from TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I need to hide first tab. First page should work but when user select it, it should be seems like on tabs is selected. How I can do this?

I found some solutions with TabHost and it useless to me.

```
public class TabFragmentClients extends Fragment {

public static TabLayout tabLayout;
public static ViewPager viewPager;
public static int int_items = 5 ;
FinanceClients FinanceClients;

public ClientsFragment clientsFragment;
public FinanceFragment financeFragment;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /**
     *Inflate tab_layout and setup Views.
     */
    final View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout_clients,null);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    /**
     *Set an Apater for the View Pager
     */
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

    /**
     * Now , this is a workaround ,
     * The setupWithViewPager dose't works without the runnable .
     * Maybe a Support Library Bug .
     */
    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });
    return x;

}
```

Comment: Could you explain more about your question?

Comment: There are actually 5 tabs. I need 4 of them visible and 1 hide. First tab should be like off the screen.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026653/how-to-hide-a-tab-in-android-tab-layout) solution. It uses tabHost, maybe you have used it wrong!

Answer (score 6):

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(desiredPosition).setVisibility(View.GONE);//hides the tab
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you try this?

```
 tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
 tabLayout.removeTabAt(0);
```

Comment: This code is for remove not for the hide.But if you removed the tab than you can simply add again for this code " mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(title)); "