# Hide Tab in Tablayout Android

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Unfortunately the [other question wasn't answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145645/android-how-to-hide-tab-from-tablayout) about how to hide a Tab in `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`.
The others questions are made with `TabHost`, I don't want to change my code.

I would like to hide the tab "Three".

[image]

---

**Fragment:**

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_viewPager);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerListener);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_tabs);
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

---

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_tabs"
    style="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:elevation="1dp" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/search_viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you link the other question you looked at and explain why that solution didn't work for you? This is either a duplicate question, or it needs to be tweaked with more explanation.

Comment: please, share the source code

Comment: Can't suggest anything without the applicable code

Comment: please, share also the source code that adds the tabs to the TabLayout

Comment: Hi the viewpager has a adapter (List) with my elements, so when i add the adapter into the viewPager and the viewPager into the tab the tab automatic get the same number of tabs as elements in my adapter

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can access the TabView of a TabLayout through `tablayout.getTabAt(int index)` and cast it as `LinearLayout` so you can set it's visibility to GONE

`((LinearLayout) tabLayout.getTabAt(0).view).setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Answer (score 9):

```
 //To hide the first tab 
 ((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
 //Set the next  tab as selected tab
 TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
 tab.select();
```

Comment: this is not the right way to do it and it doesn't work

Comment: It works in my case. Thanks. Just to handle null pointer exception here.

Answer (score 4):

modify the `adaterList` you pass to the `viewpager`: delete the third element "Three", so it will disappear

**EDIT**

when the third tab should appear, simply update `adapterList/viewPager`. You can have some ideas studying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849552/update-viewpager-dynamically)

Comment: Sorry that is not exactly what i want the search has 3 differents types of search 2 of they are in the application the three one should only appear when the other 2 does not show a result. Like a web search.
I really would like to hide this option as longer as in my app the other 2 options can be found.
So these was the reason that i would like to hide and not to delete the tab.

Comment: when the third tab should appear, simply update adapterList/viewPager. You can have some ides studying [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849552/update-viewpager-dynamically)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to save the previous view(if you used any custom view inside tab item):

```
View view=tab_layout.getTabAt(3).getCustomView();
```

Then to remove the tab at index idx(say index 2):

```
tab_layout.removeTabAt(idx);
```

Then to restore that tab, use:

```
tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setCustomView(view));
```

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin you can hide Tab after defining TabLayoutMediator as below

```
TabLayoutMediator(
        tabLayout,
        viewPager
    ) { tab, position ->
        tab.text = when (position) {
            // define tab titles
        }
    }.attach()    

((tabLayout.getTabAt(position)?.view))?.isVisible = false
```

Comment: this is way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use code below

```
var tabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(YOUR_TAB_LAYOUT_ID);
tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(YOUR_CUSTOM_VIEWPAGER);

**tabLayout.GetTabAt(0).View.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;**
```

For making it happen, just insert dummy tab to index 0. You can do it in your custom viewpager adapter. Here is code.

```
adapter.addFragment(Fragmetn.NewInstance(), "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for

```
 ((LinearLayout) Objects.requireNonNull(tabLayout.getTabAt(1)).view).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```