# How to hide the tab when scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm using a `FrameLayout` with `NestedScrollView` on it I open a fragment with 3 tabs.

Everything is appearing correctly, but scrolling down should hide my `ActionBar`.

I've done everything I think I'm wrong in some detail, could anyone help me?

Is it possible to also scroll while hiding my TABS?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--<include layout="@layout/content_main" />-->

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <!-- Your content here -->
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5026865/4748607) to hide tabbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to also scroll while hiding my TABS?

**First:** In your `Toolbar`, you have set :  `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` and this means it will be pinned at top. Then after, `app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll"` means it should be scrollable and pass when scrolling `Activity`.

So, remove: `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` from `Toolbar`.

**Second:** remove `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` from `CoordinatorLayout` also.

I couldn't see any *Tabs* in the `layout`, i suppose you are using `TabLayout` inside `Fragment`s. If you are trying to hide `TabLayout` + `Toolbar`, place `FrameLayout` inside the `NestedScrollView` then, place `TabLayout` under the `Toolbar` and inside `AppBarLayout` then if you set:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll"
```

To both `Toolbar` and `TabLayout` they will be hidden after scrolling.